# Python csv Search using index read from another file

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a test results file (test.csv) and looking for specific row which contains keywords read from a text file (index.txt).

Below is my code but it does not work.

```
indexTxt = open('index.txt', 'r')
indexLines = indexTxt.readlines()

results = open('test.csv', 'r')
resultLines = results.readlines()

for indexLine in indexLines:
    for line in resultsLines:
        if indexLine in line:
           print ("Read Line1: %s" % line)
```

Suppose my index.txt contains below:

```
TestLine1
TestLine4
TestLine6
```

I like to search and print out the matching rows.

Appreciate your advise.

Thanks

Comment: Somehow my indentation is wrong in my post. Pls ignore them and advise on the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `if indexLine in line`. `if indexLine == line`: might work if they're completely identical, or you might want to do some work with `.strip()` to remove extra whitespace.

I'd also advise adding a `print("index: '%s', text: '%s'", indexLine, line)` or similar statement in the loop to double-check the precise text.

Comment: Thanks palfrey. I actually tried editing the if indexLine in line to a string e.g. if 'TestLine1' in line - and that worked. So I am not exactly sure why indexLine doesn't work. I check that indexLine.__class__ gives back a string. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Have you tried adding the print I suggested? It may find a rogue newline or similar in your test text

Comment: Yes and it helped me see that indexLines had \r\n at the back.

Comment: I used split to remove \r and was able to match the first line - 'TestLine1' in this case but it doesn't continue to search for the other 2 lines 'TestLine4' and TestLine6.